# Binds dataframe in rows when duplicated id

Tags: r, loops, duplicates, rbind

I have a dataframe in R with duplicated ID that I want to align on the same row.

```
df <- data_frame(id = c("A1", "A2", "C2", "A2", "C2", "A2"),
             date = c("2010-01-15", "2016-03-05", "2017-05-21", "2013-09-03", "2015-11-25", "2011-07-07"),
             iT = c("z", "z", "v", "w", "z", "v"))
```

I would like to align each ID on the same row with a for loop but can only subset one variable at a time (when I actually have about 10 in reality).

```
datalist = list()
datalist1 = list()
unique_id <- unique(df$id)
for (i in unique_id) {
  subdf <- subset(df$date, df$id == i)
  datalist[[i]] <- subdf
  subdf1 <- subset(df$iT, df$id == i)
  datalist1[[i]] <- subdf1
}
df1 <- plyr::ldply(datalist, rbind)
df2 <- plyr::ldply(datalist1, rbind)
df3 <- merge.data.frame(df1,df2, by.x = ".id", by.y = ".id")
```

I have thousands rows like that with 2 to 7 duplicated ID

Here is what I wish:

```
df3 <- data_frame(id = c("A1", "A2", "C2"),
  date1 = c("2010-01-15", "2016-03-05", "2017-05-21"),
  iT = c("z", "z", "v"),
  date2 = c("NA", "2013-09-03","2015-11-25"),
  iT.2 = c("NA", "w", "z"),
  date3 = c("NA", "2011-07-07", "NA"),
  iT.3 = c("NA", "v", "NA"))
```

Comment: as in you want one id per row? Like a wide format data.frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dcast()` can reshape multiple value columns at once:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), id ~ rowid(id), value.var = c("date", "iT"))
```

> ```
>    id     date_1     date_2     date_3 iT_1 iT_2 iT_3
> 1: A1 2010-01-15       <NA>       <NA>    z <NA> <NA>
> 2: A2 2016-03-05 2013-09-03 2011-07-07    z    w    v
> 3: C2 2017-05-21 2015-11-25       <NA>    v    z <NA>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

"align on the same row" = reshape. ;)

**Base R (reshape)**

```
df <- as.data.frame(df)[order(df$id),] # Convert to data frame and order by id
df$time <- ave(df$id, df$id, FUN=seq_along) # Add "time" variable.

stats::reshape(df, direction="wide", v.names=c("date","iT")) # just one line.
```

---

```
  id     date.1 iT.1     date.2 iT.2     date.3 iT.3
1 A1 2010-01-15    z       <NA> <NA>       <NA> <NA>
2 A2 2016-03-05    z 2013-09-03    w 2011-07-07    v
3 C2 2017-05-21    v 2015-11-25    z       <NA> <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, you can get the data in long format, create an unique id for every combination of `id` and column name  and get data back to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>%
  group_by(id, name) %>%
  mutate(name1 = paste0(name, row_number())) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-name) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name1, values_from = value)

#  id    date1      iT1   date2      iT2   date3      iT3  
#  <chr> <chr>      <chr> <chr>      <chr> <chr>      <chr>
#1 A1    2010-01-15 z     NA         NA    NA         NA   
#2 A2    2016-03-05 z     2013-09-03 w     2011-07-07 v    
#3 C2    2017-05-21 v     2015-11-25 z     NA         NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider base R with `transform`, `ave`, `seq_along`, `reshape`, `grep`, `merge`, `paste0`, and `outer`:

```
# CREATE A RUNNING GROUP NUMBER FOR RESHAPING
df$id_num <- with(transform(df, n=1), ave(n, id, FUN=seq_along))

# MERGE TWO WIDE FORMAT SETS FOR date and iT
df <- merge(reshape(df[c("id", "id_num", names(df)[grep("date", names(df))])], 
                    v.names = "date", timevar = "id_num", direction = "wide"),
            reshape(df[c("id", "id_num", names(df)[grep("iT", names(df))])], 
                    v.names = "iT", timevar = "id_num", direction = "wide"),
            by = "id", suffices = c("", "_"))

# RE-ORDER COLUMNS BY PAIR COMBINATIONS
df <- df[c("id", outer(c("date.", "iT."), c(1:3), paste0))]
df
#   id     date.1 iT.1     date.2 iT.2     date.3 iT.3
# 1 A1 2010-01-15    z       <NA> <NA>       <NA> <NA>
# 2 A2 2016-03-05    z 2013-09-03    w 2011-07-07    v
# 3 C2 2017-05-21    v 2015-11-25    z       <NA> <NA>
```

<kbd>[Online Demo](https://rextester.com/ZHJW9405)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Uwe is working great. For a small data I also found this way using `tidyverse`.

```
%>% group_by(id) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(date, iT), paste, collapse = "; ") %>%
  separate(col = date, paste("date", 1:10, sep=""), sep = "; ", extra = "warn", fill = "right") %>%
  separate(col = iT, paste("iT", 1:10, sep=""), sep = "; ", extra = "warn", fill = "right") %>% 
  purrr::keep(~!all(is.na(.)))
```

As I said it is better using it for small data or if you want to combine the info of the duplicate id in one cell.